# Updating parent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables namely `profile` and `table_1`, `profile` is a parent table and `table_1` is a child table. i have a `email` column in both tables and what i want to do is for example `'me@mail.com'` in the child table column `email` should update every column of the parent table column `record` with `1` where parent `email` column is `me@mail.com`.

in the where statement i use both primary keys of both tables to do it but since they are not the same it causes  mistakes.

```
update profile 
  set record= (
               select table_1.record
                 from Table_1
                where profile.profile_id = Table_1.profile_id
              )
```

but when i used this one below which i know will work it give me an error `"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >="`

```
update profile 
  set record = (
               select table_1.record
                 from Table_1
                where profile.email = Table_1.email
              )
```

please how do i make the update work with the email columns but not the primary key columns

Comment: query must return only one row, maybe with TOP 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If record is functionally dependant on email then derive a set of email, record and use that for your update

```
with s as (select distinct email, record from table1)
update t
set record = s.record
from profile t
join s on s.email = t.email
```

If for s, email /-&gt; record then the record you get from the join is not guaranteed

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you may want:

```
update P
set P.record= T.record
from profile P
Inner Join Table_1 T
    ON P.profile_id = T.profile_id
```

Any row in P that matches the ProfileId in T will get it's "Record" column updated with the value in T's "Record" column.

You can modify this to use other columns in the JOIN.  You can also add multiple columns to update in the SET portion of the code.

Comment: this code above works fine but the problem is, both profile_id of the two tables have different records so i want to use the email which they are all certainly the same to do the update

Comment: @blay So do you have any columns for a JOIN or not?

Comment: i have, that is the email. but with that, it gives the error "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >="

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a parent-child table you must have some joining condition.
I think you need to add a where condition at the end of the query mentioned in the above answer:

```
        update P
        set P.record= T.record
        from profile p 
        Inner Join Table_1 T
        ON (Since parent-child, you must have a joining condition)
        where p.email = t.email
```